# Redirecting fprintf and disp output of different parfor workers/threads to separate windows

Tags: linux, multithreading, matlab, unix, printf

I have thousands of lines of MATLAB code that realizes different computationally intensive operations on fMRI brain-imaging data. Many of the operations could be run in multiple parallel threads, but the problem is that all `fprintf` and `disp` output of different threads/workers is printed on the same window.

I have written a custom multithreading code that forks out new MATLAB instances using `unix` command in Linux environment. So, I first write out .m-files PreprocessSubj1.m, PreprocessSubj2.m, PreprocessSubj3.m and PreprocessSubj4.m, each of these contains the same computations but for different subjects. These 4 MATLAB functions are completely independent of each other.

```
CellArrayOfFunctions = { 'PreprocessSubj1', 'PreprocessSubj2', ...
'PreprocessSubj3', 'PreprocessSubj4' };

CellArrayOfFunctions_i = 1;

while (CellArrayOfFunctions_i <= size(CellArrayOfFunctions, 2))
    FunctionToBeRun = CellArrayOfFunctions{CellArrayOfFunctions_i};
    unix([ 'matlab -desktop -r ', FunctionToBeRun, ' &' ]);
    CellArrayOfFunctions_i = CellArrayOfFunctions_i + 1;
end
```

I think using `unix` for forking MATLAB threads is quite a kludge. I would like to implement this code using `parfor`, for better maintainability and smaller memory usage. But is there any way how I could redirect `fprintf` (and `disp`) output of different threads/workers to separate windows?

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know anything about Matlab but isn't there a way you can prefix your printf statements with a thread id and just write to a log?  Then tail the log, pipe the output to grep which searches for the thread id.  Do this in a different terminal for each thread you are interested in. Just a thought.

Comment: I'm a writing a separate log for each thread already, but that works only for my own code, not for fprintf statements of the MATLAB toolboxes (SPM8) I'm using. But if I'll replace MATLAB built-in fprintf with my own fprintf.m and do the same for MATLAB built-in disp, and open terminals with "tail -f $logfilename.txt", this could be a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to write to /dev/pts/#, where # will denote the window. You can do this with:

```
output1 = fopen('/dev/pts/0', 'w');
output2 = fopen('/dev/pts/1', 'w');
fwrite(output1, 'Data to window 1');
fwrite(output2, 'Data to window 2');
```

You will need to determine which numbers to put after /dev/pts/ somehow though. Each time you open a new terminal, a new file appears there corresponding to that terminal, so you can check what terminals are available with `!ls /dev/pts`.

Comment: This could be a possible solution or a part of it. Thank you.